# YOUKU video, hiding controls & related videos and enable autoplay

Tags: autoplay, youku

I am using youku video in my react site. anyone please help me to hide the controls & related videos. also the autoplay is not working with the code.

code snippet:

```
{!defaultVideoPlayer && youkoID && (
      <iframe
     // src={`https://player.youku.com/embed/${youkoID}`}

        src={`https://player.youku.com/embed/${youkoID}?rel=0&autoplay=${autoplay}&loop=${loop}&showinfo=0&controls=0&mute=${muted}&playlist=${youkoID}`}
        frameBorder="0"
        allowFullScreen
        title="Yokou video"
      />
    )}
```